# ¿Cómo puedo correr correctamente esta imagen a la izquierda? Sin que se robe el espacio del "Article" de arriba

Tags: css

al llevar las imágenes hacia la izquierda, la de la segunda posición se roba este espacio.

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
  @media (min-width:480px) {
  .entrada img {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    /* lleva imagen hacia la izquierda*/
  }
```

```html
<article class="entrada">
  <h2>Viajar a londres</h2>
  <img src="img/imagen_1.jpg" alt="Imagen viajar a Londres">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique labore obcaecati inventore quis recusandae id perferendis itaque voluptas beatae? Nostrum ratione laudantium earum voluptate ipsum temporibus illum placeat corporis esse.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic quos imus officia iure magni ea. Velit incidunt aliquam repellat quia excepturi quisquam. Esse adipisci odit molestias accusamus dolores.</p>
  <a href="#" class="boton">Ler más </a>
</article>
<article class="entrada">
  <h2>Puente de la torre</h2>
  <img src="img/imagen_1.jpg" alt="Imagen viajar a Puente de la torre">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique labore obcaecati inventore quis recusandae id perferendis </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic quos perferendis quo, possimus officia iure magni ea. Velit incidunt aliquam repellat quia excepturi quisquam. Esse adipisci odit molestias accusamus dolores.</p>
  <a href="#" class="boton">Ler más </a>
</article>
<article class="entrada">
  <h2>Metro de Londres</h2>
  <img src="img/imagen_3.jpg" alt="Imagen Metro de Londres">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique labore obcaecati inventore quis recusandae id perferendis itaque voluptas beatae? Nostrum ratione laudantium earum voluptate ipsum temporibus illum placeat corporis esse.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic quos peEsse adipisci odit molestias accusamus dolores.</p>
  <a href="#" class="boton">Ler más </a>
</article>
```

Comment: Bienvenido. Deberías colocar el código para que se pueda ayudar.

Comment: Bienvenido Juan... Por favor pon tu codigo. Y agrega la etiqueta html ya que también está involucrado...

Comment: Podrías colocar unas imagenes de la web con el mismo size? Para que pase el codigo a mi VSC y haga el CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Ahora con flex y grid puedes solucionarlo con facilidad. Solo agrega un para separar la imagen de los textos

```
    <article class="entrada">
  <h2>Viajar a londres</h2>
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff" alt="Imagen viajar a Londres">
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique labore obcaecati inventore quis recusandae id perferendis itaque voluptas beatae? Nostrum ratione laudantium earum voluptate ipsum temporibus illum placeat corporis esse.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic quos imus officia iure magni ea. Velit incidunt aliquam repellat quia excepturi quisquam. Esse adipisci odit molestias accusamus dolores.</p>
    <a href="#" class="boton">Ler más </a>
  </div>
</article>
<article class="entrada">
  <h2>Puente de la torre</h2>
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff" alt="Imagen viajar a Puente de la torre">
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique labore obcaecati inventore quis recusandae id perferendis itaque voluptas beatae? Nostrum ratione laudantium earum voluptate ipsum temporibus illum placeat corporis esse.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic quos imus officia iure magni ea. Velit incidunt aliquam repellat quia excepturi quisquam. Esse adipisci odit molestias accusamus dolores.</p>
    <a href="#" class="boton">Ler más </a>
  </div>
</article>
<article class="entrada">
  <h2>Metro de Londres</h2>
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff" alt="Imagen Metro de Londres">
 <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique labore obcaecati inventore quis recusandae id perferendis itaque voluptas beatae? Nostrum ratione laudantium earum voluptate ipsum temporibus illum placeat corporis esse.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic quos imus officia iure magni ea. Velit incidunt aliquam repellat quia excepturi quisquam. Esse adipisci odit molestias accusamus dolores.</p>
    <a href="#" class="boton">Ler más </a>
  </div>
</article>
```

Y el css quedaría así:

```
    .entrada {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2em 0;
}

.entrada h2 {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}

.entrada img {
  float: left;
  flex: 300px 0 0;
}

.entrada div {
  flex: calc(100% - 400px);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

simplemente use bootstrap

Con el sistema de cuadrícula, puede hacer lo que quiera sin molestar al usuario móvil, aquí está toda la documentación, incluidos ejemplos de código: https://getbootstrap.com.br/docs/4.1/layout/overview/

Lo explicaré muy brevemente para que nadie quede sin un norte;

cree un archivo html vacío para comenzar:

primero inserte esto en la etiqueta `<head>` de la página:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

luego ingrese esto en la parte inferior de la página, más antes de `</body>`

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

ahora hazlo de esta manera:

```
<!--- crear tres columnas una al lado de la otra en línea recta --->

    <!--- establecer una caja con ancho máximo -->

    <div class="container">

       <!--- inicio de agrupación de elementos --->
      <div class="row">
        <!--- establecer el tamaño de la columna --->
        <div class="col-sm">
          el contenido de la primera columna aquí
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
          el contenido de la segunda columna aquí
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
          el contenido de la tercera columna aquí
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Aquí está el diseño listo para ti: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/blog/

Aquí hay más ejemplos de implementación: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/

Si tienes alguna pregunta, cuenta conmigo.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
    <meta name="generator" content="Jekyll v3.8.5">
    <title>Product example · Bootstrap</title>

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/product/">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <style>
      .bd-placeholder-img {
        font-size: 1.125rem;
        text-anchor: middle;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
      }

      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
          font-size: 3.5rem;
        }
      }
    </style>
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="product.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="site-header sticky-top py-1">
  <div class="container d-flex flex-column flex-md-row justify-content-between">
    <a class="py-2" href="#">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" class="d-block mx-auto" role="img" viewBox="0 0 24 24" focusable="false"><title>Product</title><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"/><path d="M14.31 8l5.74 9.94M9.69 8h11.48M7.38 12l5.74-9.94M9.69 16L3.95 6.06M14.31 16H2.83m13.79-4l-5.74 9.94"/></svg>
    </a>
    <a class="py-2 d-none d-md-inline-block" href="#">Tour</a>
    <a class="py-2 d-none d-md-inline-block" href="#">Product</a>
    <a class="py-2 d-none d-md-inline-block" href="#">Features</a>
    <a class="py-2 d-none d-md-inline-block" href="#">Enterprise</a>
    <a class="py-2 d-none d-md-inline-block" href="#">Support</a>
    <a class="py-2 d-none d-md-inline-block" href="#">Pricing</a>
    <a class="py-2 d-none d-md-inline-block" href="#">Cart</a>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="position-relative overflow-hidden p-3 p-md-5 m-md-3 text-center bg-light">
  <div class="col-md-5 p-lg-5 mx-auto my-5">
    <h1 class="display-4 font-weight-normal">Punny headline</h1>
    <p class="lead font-weight-normal">And an even wittier subheading to boot. Jumpstart your marketing efforts with this example based on Apple’s marketing pages.</p>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary" href="#">Coming soon</a>
  </div>
  <div class="product-device shadow-sm d-none d-md-block"></div>
  <div class="product-device product-device-2 shadow-sm d-none d-md-block"></div>
</div>

<div class="d-md-flex flex-md-equal w-100 my-md-3 pl-md-3">
  <div class="bg-dark mr-md-3 pt-3 px-3 pt-md-5 px-md-5 text-center text-white overflow-hidden">
    <div class="my-3 py-3">
      <h2 class="display-5">Another headline</h2>
      <p class="lead">And an even wittier subheading.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-light shadow-sm mx-auto" style="width: 80%; height: 300px; border-radius: 21px 21px 0 0;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-light mr-md-3 pt-3 px-3 pt-md-5 px-md-5 text-center overflow-hidden">
    <div class="my-3 p-3">
      <h2 class="display-5">Another headline</h2>
      <p class="lead">And an even wittier subheading.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-dark shadow-sm mx-auto" style="width: 80%; height: 300px; border-radius: 21px 21px 0 0;"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="d-md-flex flex-md-equal w-100 my-md-3 pl-md-3">
  <div class="bg-light mr-md-3 pt-3 px-3 pt-md-5 px-md-5 text-center overflow-hidden">
    <div class="my-3 p-3">
      <h2 class="display-5">Another headline</h2>
      <p class="lead">And an even wittier subheading.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-dark shadow-sm mx-auto" style="width: 80%; height: 300px; border-radius: 21px 21px 0 0;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-primary mr-md-3 pt-3 px-3 pt-md-5 px-md-5 text-center text-white overflow-hidden">
    <div class="my-3 py-3">
      <h2 class="display-5">Another headline</h2>
      <p class="lead">And an even wittier subheading.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-light shadow-sm mx-auto" style="width: 80%; height: 300px; border-radius: 21px 21px 0 0;"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="d-md-flex flex-md-equal w-100 my-md-3 pl-md-3">
  <div class="bg-light mr-md-3 pt-3 px-3 pt-md-5 px-md-5 text-center overflow-hidden">
    <div class="my-3 p-3">
      <h2 class="display-5">Another headline</h2>
      <p class="lead">And an even wittier subheading.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-white shadow-sm mx-auto" style="width: 80%; height: 300px; border-radius: 21px 21px 0 0;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-light mr-md-3 pt-3 px-3 pt-md-5 px-md-5 text-center overflow-hidden">
    <div class="my-3 py-3">
      <h2 class="display-5">Another headline</h2>
      <p class="lead">And an even wittier subheading.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-white shadow-sm mx-auto" style="width: 80%; height: 300px; border-radius: 21px 21px 0 0;"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="d-md-flex flex-md-equal w-100 my-md-3 pl-md-3">
  <div class="bg-light mr-md-3 pt-3 px-3 pt-md-5 px-md-5 text-center overflow-hidden">
    <div class="my-3 p-3">
      <h2 class="display-5">Another headline</h2>
      <p class="lead">And an even wittier subheading.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-white shadow-sm mx-auto" style="width: 80%; height: 300px; border-radius: 21px 21px 0 0;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-light mr-md-3 pt-3 px-3 pt-md-5 px-md-5 text-center overflow-hidden">
    <div class="my-3 py-3">
      <h2 class="display-5">Another headline</h2>
      <p class="lead">And an even wittier subheading.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-white shadow-sm mx-auto" style="width: 80%; height: 300px; border-radius: 21px 21px 0 0;"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<footer class="container py-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" class="d-block mb-2" role="img" viewBox="0 0 24 24" focusable="false"><title>Product</title><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"/><path d="M14.31 8l5.74 9.94M9.69 8h11.48M7.38 12l5.74-9.94M9.69 16L3.95 6.06M14.31 16H2.83m13.79-4l-5.74 9.94"/></svg>
      <small class="d-block mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2017-2019</small>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md">
      <h5>Features</h5>
      <ul class="list-unstyled text-small">
        <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Cool stuff</a></li>
        <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Random feature</a></li>
        <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Team feature</a></li>
        <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Stuff for developers</a></li>
        <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Another one</a></li>
        <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Last time</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md">
      <h5>Resources</h5>
      <ul class="list-unstyled text-small">
        <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Resource</a></li>
        <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Resource name</a></li>
        <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Another resource</a></li>
        <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Final resource</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md">
      <h5>Resources</h5>
      <ul class="list-unstyled text-small">
        <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Business</a></li>
        <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Education</a></li>
        <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Government</a></li>
        <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Gaming</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md">
      <h5>About</h5>
      <ul class="list-unstyled text-small">
        <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Team</a></li>
        <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Locations</a></li>
        <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Privacy</a></li>
        <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Terms</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/assets/js/vendor/jquery-slim.min.js"><\/script>')</script><script src="https://getbootstrap.com/https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-xrRywqdh3PHs8keKZN+8zzc5TX0GRTLCcmivcbNJWm2rs5C8PRhcEn3czEjhAO9o" crossorigin="anonymous"></script></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Demasiado amable.